# How can I pass a value from input field to a select option using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code to pass a value from a `select` option to a given `input` field.

```js
$(".itemconditionmenu").change(function() {
  var conditionofitem = $(this).val();
  $("#meta_itemcondition").val(conditionofitem);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="itemcondition" class="itemconditionmenu">
  <option value="">Choose Condition</option>
  <option value="New">New</option>
  <option value="Used">Used</option>
</select>
<input id="meta_itemcondition" type="text" value="New">
```

But how can I pass the value of the `input` field back to the `select` option value using jQuery?

Comment: Please include your html

Comment: You only need to change the selectors around. The same logic will work - assuming the `select` has an `option` matching the value entered.

Comment: you want to add  a option in select field as per your input text?

Comment: @Amit i want the default value of the select box be the value of the input field.

Comment: but your code is working well, what do you want?  I am still confused sorry.
If you write 'abc' in your input field, it should be appear in select field?

Comment: The snippet works?

Comment: @Amit if you run the code snippet you will notice that the input field has the value: "Choose condition" I want to force it so it will get the specific value of the input field

Comment: @Designer It does? When you run the snippet and select a value from the dropdown, it sets the value of the input box

Comment: @JamesS i want the default value of the select box to be the value of the input field

Comment: @Designer What if your input box has no value? What would your dropdown show then? Nothing?

Comment: @JamesS the input field has always a value as default (New or Used). Never is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I am not sure what you are exactly looking, however, as per my understanding I have modifed your code samples.. You can check below snippet.**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var conditionofitem = $("#meta_itemcondition").val();
    $(".itemconditionmenu").val(conditionofitem);
});

$(".itemconditionmenu").change(function() {
  var conditionofitem = $(this).val();
  if(conditionofitem == '') {
     $("#meta_itemcondition").val('Choose Condition');
   } else {
      $("#meta_itemcondition").val(conditionofitem);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="itemcondition" class="itemconditionmenu">
  <option value="">Choose Condition</option>
  <option value="New">New</option>
  <option value="Used">Used</option>
</select>
<input id="meta_itemcondition" type="text" value="New">
```

**Please check and let me know if you have any further queries.**

Comment: I want exactly what you did but vice versa. The select box must have the value of the input field not the opposite. Thank you

Comment: means if you type "New" then dropdown will be automatically selected "New" option, right?

Comment: No. When the page loads the input field has the value "new" as default. I want it so the select box has also the same value selected as default. So in summary there must be a way to tell the select box has the same value as the input field on page load. I dont touch at all the input field as in my form is hidden.

Comment: Please check now..is it okay?

Comment: Yeahhh! OK this is exactly what i wanted !!

Comment: Great, I am feeling happy to hear that, please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign if it's helpful. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$("#addOption").click(function(){
  $("#itemconditionmenu").append('<option value="'+$("#meta_itemcondition").val()+'" selected="selected">'+$("#meta_itemcondition").val()+'</option>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="itemconditionmenu">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<input id="meta_itemcondition" type="text" value=""></input>
<button id="addOption">ADD</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Example for the same: Blur out your input and value option will be added to select dropdown

```js
$(".itemconditionmenu").change(function() {
  var conditionofitem = $(this).val();
  $("#meta_itemcondition").val(conditionofitem);
});

$("#meta_itemcondition").blur(function() {

  var inputValue = $(this).val();
  var o = new Option(inputValue, inputValue);
  $(o).html(inputValue);
  $("#itemcondition").append(o);
  $("#itemcondition").val(inputValue);
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
  var value =  $("#meta_itemcondition").val();
  console.log(value)
  var alreadyOption = false;
  $("#itemcondition option").each(function()
    {
      alreadyOption = $(this).val() === value;
      if(alreadyOption) {
        $("#itemcondition").val(value);
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="itemcondition" class="itemconditionmenu">
  <option value="">Choose Condition</option>
  <option value="New">New</option>
  <option value="Used">Used</option>
</select>
<input id="meta_itemcondition" type="text" value="New"/>
```

Comment: It doesnt work. When you run the snippet the value of the select is "Choose Condition" instead of  "New"

Comment: @Designer i thought you want it in option. I edited the code.

Comment: @Designer did you try now ??

Comment: Still doesnt work. When you run the script the value of the select box option is still "Choose condition" and not "new" as it should be.

Comment: Preloading itself you want it to be selected ?? can you edit input value At that time it takes new value

Comment: @Designer given the functionality if you edit input and same will be added to select box

Answer (score 0):

**Here you can find inline functionality**

1. if you enter a value in textbox value append in drop-down
2. if you select drop-down value auto set in textbox.

**Note: add value in textbox change just input focus**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<select class="jsSelect" onchange="$('.jsTextBox').val($(this).val())"> 
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<input class="jsTextBox" onchange="if($(this).val()!=''){$('.jsSelect').append($('<option></option>').attr('value',$(this).val()).text($(this).val()));$('.jsSelect').val($(this).val());}" type="text" value="">
```